# CD tray won't open. What can I do?

Tags: hardware, cd-drive

That's about it. Whenever I press the eject button on my cd player, nothing happens. CD player is not the cause of the problem because this never happens to me under Windows. Any suggestions?

In addition, running the eject command from a terminal also does nothing.

More information : I am running ubuntu 10.04 64 bits, have previously read a CD (like 2 hours ago), which I ejected using nautilus because I couldn't eject it using the same hardware button.

Here is the output of the command 'eject -v' :

```
eject: using default device `cdrom'
eject: device name is `cdrom'
eject: expanded name is `/dev/cdrom'
eject: `/dev/cdrom' is a link to `/dev/sr0'
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not mounted
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not a mount point
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not a multipartition device
eject: trying to eject `/dev/sr0' using CD-ROM eject command
eject: CD-ROM eject command failed
eject: trying to eject `/dev/sr0' using SCSI commands
eject: SCSI eject succeeded
```

UPDATE: Ok I would like to add that I am unable to reproduce this bug, as I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10 using said CD, and behavior seems ok now. It was probably the upgrade to a more recent kernel that did the trick. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is the output of `eject -v`?

Comment: what hardware is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does

```
sudo umount /dev/cdrom
sudo eject /dev/cdrom
```

work?

If not can you eject the CD whilst the PC is at the BIOS screen?

Comment: for clarification, if you have more than one cd drive, you may need to switch /dev/cdrom with /dev/cdrom1, /dev/cdrom2 etc for the number of drives you have until you eject the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Try `hdparm -L 0 /dev/cdrom`, and then `eject`?

Answer (score 3):

Try sticking a needle or a pin in the small hole from the CD drive. That should get it.

Comment: +1, Just to add that drives vary so a quick search for 'Eject pin hole' plus your brand of drive may help. This method ALWAYS works, but might not be good for the drive.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using a Live CD and then ejecting. Might help determine if it's a bug with Ubuntu, or your installation.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sudo eject
```

on the command line.

Comment: Still doesn't work. 'sudo eject -v' outputs the same thing as 'eject -v'.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to reproduce this bug. It occurred for me twice the same way when I accidentally moved some files I was burning to a CD. Performing the `eject -v` command I get the same output as the OP. Unfortunately, at the time of posting this I have not fixed the issue. The first time it happened, I was able to eject the tray at the BIOS screen, but this time that didn't work. I tried `sudo umount /dev/cdrom` and got the output `umount: /dev/cdrom: not mounted`. `sudo eject -v` did the same thing at this point. I tried `hdparm -L 0 /dev/cdrom` and got the output

```
/dev/cdrom: 
setting drive doorlock to 0 (off) 
HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(doorlock) failed: Bad address
```

Comment: Which version are you using? My bug was using a distro that is now over 2 years old.

Perhaps you should open a new question?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing helped from the answers above.

Create file

```
/etc/sysctl.d/20-no-cdrom-lock.conf 
dev.cdrom.lock=0
```

for testing before run

```
sudo sysctl dev.cdrom.lock=0
```